# Field in Azure SQL database ends up null even though it has data on client side

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I'm using `MobileServiceClient` and `IMobileServiceTable` to communicate with the Azure SQL database.

I'm using it to store a somewhat large data object (~6kb) encoded as `Base64String` (end length ~10k characters). The object has data when I call await `IMobileServiceTable.InsertAsync(dataEntry)`, however in the database this field ends up null.

This only happens when uploading from Windows Phone 8.1 App. I am using the same code, that connects to the same mobile service from a Windows Store App and there the data is uploaded without a problem.

No error is thrown when I call `InsertAsync`, just the one field contains `null` in the database.

What is going on here? I was unable to find any documentation about size limitations when uploading from Windows Phone. How can I get around this?

**EDIT:** I have just tried it on a WP8.0 device, and I observed the same behavior.

**EDIT2:** I have tried with the smallest package I can generate, with the string length of just 820. Still the same result, it ends up as null in the database.

I am sure that the database and the client service are both in order, since I can store the same object from Windows Store app without a problem (same code, same object, same size and the same destination).

Comment: What do you see when you watch the network connections with something like Fiddler or WireShark?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Unfortunately I'm unable to get fiddler to work on the phone. I would guess it has something to do with the firewall on the computer that I of course cannot meddle with (corporate pc and whatnot)

Comment: Can you trigger the same behaviour from the WP8.1 emulator? You might be able to install fiddler on your own pc and capture the traffic like that. Also, what is in the token you get from `InsertAsync`? (btw, I can't @ complete your name, so apologies if you don't get notified)

Comment: @BenjaminDiele can't try in the emulator. InsertAsync returns a Task, and I await that task. No exception is thrown. Is there another token you have in mind?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele also I've added another edit to the question. It would seem that the size of the string isn't the problem, as the same thing happens even with only 820 characters.

Comment: is your client able to get data from azure? Btw, have you checked your permissions and capabilities in your app manifest?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Yes reading seems to work fine, also all the other data is stored successfully. What permissions should I be looking at?

Comment: If you can store other data, it's not a permissions problem, so no need to check. Could it be that the column you're trying to add is a protected keyword or something like that? Can you add your `dataEntry` to your question?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Actually I've solved to problem. It lay completely elsewhere, in Json.net (and different behaviors on different platforms.) Sorry to have wasted your time, if it helps it wasted a lot of mine too!

Comment: Haha, no problem man. Happy you solved it! If possible, could you post an answer to your question and mark it solved? That way the next user knows a possible solution.